# Creating a new Page class in Metro that can use Top/Bottom AppBars

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm using the WinRT XAML Toolkit for my Metro app - more specifically, the `AlternativeFrame` and `AlternativePage` classes. They're extremely useful, and necessary for their Preload functions. However, I have need of AppBars, which these don't provide. Now it's easy enough to derive a new class from the `AlternativePage` and add a `DependencyProperty` called BottomAppBar/TopAppBar with type AppBar... However, how can I make the AppBar's behave in the same way as the native Page class? So they appear on right-click as well as the up-gesture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put the AppBars inside of the pages. They are just regular controls and while Microsoft doesn't recommend it - you can use them that way. You can also use the CustomAppBar control from the toolkit instead of the standard AppBars for some more fine grained control and to get the standard-looking slide transitions.